# Why is Bella's unborn child referred to as a devil?

Tags: twilight, breaking-dawn

In *Twilight Breaking Dawn Part 1*, why is Bella's unborn child referred to as "Devil"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, here are some reasons:

- The child is born of the union between Vampire and Human.
- Some cultures consider Vampires a devil, so their offspring would be considered a devil too.
- As the baby grows it requires warm blood or else it takes it from it's mother.
- It kills the mother on birth.
- Grows at a much faster rate than humans. (Even the pregnancy is much shorter)
- It has 24 chromosome pairs, while a human has 23, further differentiating it from humans.

I suppose it depends on one's definition of a "Devil".

Sources:
http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: You forgot the most important thing: "she's in Twilight". :)